# Using mouse as input device c++

Tags: c++, windows, dev-c++

I've run across some information across the net using the mouse in a C++ console, but I am still new to the language and confused.

I am using the Dev C++ compiler on Windows 7 and want to use the mouse to click and capture an input from the console screen, is this possible with the standard libraries? How would I use the mouse to cin?

Comment: Not with the standard libraries it isn't. Windows has something like `SetConsoleMode` to allow mouse usage.

Comment: If you are talking about using the mouse for copy or paste, Windows should treat the paste as standard input to your console program.  Windows already has a feature to highlight text in a console and put it on the clipboard.

Comment: This feature is known as QuickEdit Mode and can be configured manually in console properties.

Comment: Understanding what you're trying to do a bit more, be aware that quickedit won't work with the mode set to enable the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

What's preventing you from using Win32? It will be much easier to use the mouse here since all you need to do is handle messages. More information on what you're trying to achieve might help us in finding you the best solution.

By the way, Dev C++ last I saw is very old and I believe no longer maintained. Eclipse is better (even it if is sometimes intolerable). You can also use Visual Studio 2010/2012 Express editions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with standard C++ input/output.

You need to use Win32 Console API and enable [`ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT Low-Level Console Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Then you will be able to read mouse events using [`ReadConsoleInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`PeekConsoleInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API functions.

See [MSDN example on reading console input events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Please note that mouse cursor position is provided in terms of the console screen buffer's character-cell coordinates, not pixel-wise coordinates.